# Change the CSS class of a <a> tag when clicking on it with AJAX in ASP MVC

Tags: css, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this tag

```
<a href="#" class="bt_off" title="OFF">OFF</a>
```

What I want to do is to make the class attribute change to "bt_on" when I click on it, using Ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not AJAX. It's simply javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use ajax, use jQuery instead

```
$("a.bt_off").bind("click", function(){
$("a.bt_off").removeClass("bt_off").addClass("bt_on");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have jquery loaded to your page

```
$(function(){

  $("a.bt_off").click(function(){
     $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_on");
  });

});
```